# JavaScript DOM Render OnLoadStart and OnLoad Function Running At The Same Time

Tags: javascript, filereader

**Question**

The below JavaScript onloadstart function will run and display the alert/log right when the import button is clicked, however after clicking ok on that alert, the finished loading alert will also display. 5 seconds later the file is actually finished and the textbox is populated.

Why are both the start and finished alerts/logs running at the beginning? I want the finished alert to run when the text box is actually populated which only happens after the file has truly been imported.

**EDIT**

Perhaps the import finishes but the text box population is taking a good 5 seconds. *<- this is actually the issue. FileReader is working fine, it's the DOM renderer that is taking up those (5 seconds).*

The issue now is how can you trigger a completion event once the render is complete.

I was curious about page refresh, and I included the below Fiddle on my site at the top of the page. Once I click import, the "tick" value stops refreshes for about 5 seconds, then resumes. Once it resumes, the textbox is also populated. Seems like the entire page refresh is halted during the textbox DOM render.

https://jsfiddle.net/mosdxrhk/

JSON file size: 6 mb

Character count of textarea after importing JSON file

`document.getElementById('importTextArea').value.length`

> 8,014,573

I also noticed that after I perform some operations on that textarea, and go to output it to another textarea the new file character count is 37 million. This ends up crashing the entire Chrome web page.

**HTML**

```
<textarea class="form-control" spellcheck="false" id="importTextArea"></textarea>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    document.getElementById('import').onclick = function() {
        var files = document.getElementById('selectFiles').files;
        console.log(files);
        if (files.length <= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onloadstart = function(e) {
            console.log("start loading");
            alert("start loading");
        }
        fr.onload = function(e) { 
            console.log(e);
            var result = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
            var formatted = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
            document.getElementById('importTextArea').value = formatted; // populated text box
            console.log("finished loading");            
            alert("finished loading");
        }
        fr.readAsText(files.item(0));
    };
```

Comment: what difference does replacing `alert` calls with calls to `console.log` make?

Comment: @traktor made a edit to the question. There is no difference in alert vs log. Also I'm not sure if the onload is looking for file upload completion or for the entire function to be completed. Either way I'm looking for a alert/log to be displayed when the text box is complete which means the upload, computation, and text box population needs to complete and then a alert/log gets triggered.

Comment: "Perhaps the import finishes but the text box population is taking a good 5 seconds." Yes, that would be the most logical explanation. How big is your JSON file? You should be able to fire a task after the whole text has been processed and rendered by doing `requestAnimationFrame(() => setTimeout(yourCallback))` inside the `onload` event handler (where `yourCallback` would be the function you want to execute).

Comment: @Kaiido this turns out to be the issue, do you have any examples that might fit in with the code posted above on `requestAnimationFrame`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is asynchronous rendering.

With the sample below, without any `FileReader`, I managed to reproduce the effect in Chromium.  Modifying the DOM does not re-render the page immediately: it only schedules a rendering cycle for the near future.  Firefox, on the other hand, does not behave in this way: when the textarea DOM node is modified, the browser performs a full rendering cycle, and only then displays the alert.

```js
function populate() {
    var rep = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rep').value);
    document.getElementById('a').value = 'a'.repeat(rep);
    alert('hi');
}
```

```html
<textarea id="a"></textarea><br>
repetitions: <input id="rep" type="number" value="5e6"><br>
<button onclick="populate()">populate</button>
```

Comment: "the browser performs a full rendering cycle", no, they do a kind of "[spin the event loop](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#spin-the-event-loop)", so in this browser the rendering engine just keeps working when the modal is shown, even if user scripts are blocked (Chrome does a similar thing with `debugger`). But this is no proof that it's really what happens to OP, they stated that they'll get the rendering happen only 5s after they closed the modal.

Comment: Well, what *exactly* happens inside different DOM engines can change with every release. I appreciate the way in which user3840170 explained the basic principle behind the asynchronous rendering, even if it might be "incorrect" in some "details".

Comment: @CarstenMassmann that what they state in their answer is interesting to you (even if wrong...) doesn't mean that it's a good answer to the question at hand. Without more information from OP we can't assert what caused what they experience.

Comment: I think the most important takeaways are: (a) calling `alert` gives no guarantee about the page being freshly rendered, and (b) this has nothing to do with `FileReader`. The actual details of how layout engines are implemented are relatively unimportant here.

Comment: @user3840170 your last comment is correct, this ends up being a issue with the render. The snippet you posted is what I am experiencing. I will update the question accordingly. Also I still need to find a way to post a notice once the render is complete.